# Can I run Ubuntu as my main OS just by using integrated graphic card?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, 21.04, integrated

I have installed Ubuntu but I have some problems with my dedicated graphic card,Can I use Ubuntu without having dedicated gpu installed ?
I don't do any game

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a dedicated GPU to run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I have Ubuntu on my laptop (Core i5, 8 GB RAM), which has no dedicated graphics, only the Intel chipset -- and it works fine, even for low-load gaming.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your CPU. I am assuming you are talking about desktop. If your CPU has integrated graphics, you can use that to run Ubuntu. But if your CPU does not have integrated  graphics (like mine, Ryzen 7 CPUs) then you need dedicated graphics card.

Comment: Current to 2021 this answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run Ubuntu without a dedicated GPU. I don't have a dedicated GPU on my PC and I had Ubuntu running for a while. Now I am using Linux Mint though.